# Obtaining the selected option in a select element with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJs, how can I obtain the selected option in a a select element, and then use this value to limit the available options in another select element?

**Code:**

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">
        Release...
    </option>
    <option ng-repeat="release in releases" value="{{ release.title }}">
        {{ release.title }}
    </option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">
        Sprint...
    </option>
    <option ng-repeat="sprint in releases[ ***selectedRelease***  ].sprints" value="{{ sprint.title }}">
        {{ sprint.title }}
    </option>
</select>
```

i.e. I would like to know what I have to put for `***selectedRelease***`?

**Data**

```
$scope.releases = [
    {   title:  'V1',
        sprints: [ 
            {   title:  'S1'    },
            {   title:  'S2'    },
            {   title:  'S3'    }
        ]               
    },
    {
        title:  'V2',
        sprints: [ 
            {   title:  'S4'    },
            {   title:  'S5'    }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular's [select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect):

```
<select ng-model="selectedRelease" ng-options="release.title for release in releases">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">
    Release...
  </option>
</select>

<select ng-options="sprint.title for sprint in selectedRelease.sprints">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">
      Sprint...
  </option>
</select>
```

In your controller, add:

```
$scope.selectedRelease = null;
```

I have created a plunk, [try it](http://plnkr.co/uOaeh5)

Comment: Thank you :) Btw: It also works without `$scope.selectedRelease = null;`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ngRepeat` on `<option>`, but rather `ngModel` on `<select>`. The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) for this subject is really very well done.

```
<select ng-model="selectedRelease" ng-options="release.title for (key, release) in releases">
    <option value="">
        Release...
    </option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedSprint" ng-options="sprint.title for (key, sprint) in releases[selectedRelease].sprints">
    <option value="">
        Sprint...
    </option>
</select>
```